# How do I grow and shrink a double-pointer dynamic array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm learning C++ and I'm expected to use a double pointer to build a dynamic array of objects that grows and shrinks as elements are added and removes from the array.

I can create the array like so:

```
Person** people = new Person*[10];
```

And add objects like so:

```
people[0] = new Person(“Luke”);
people[1] = new Person(“Han”);
people[2] = new Person(“Leia”);
```

And delete objects like so:

```
delete people[1]
people[1] = null;
```

(At least I think that's correct.)

But I'm stuck on several things...

Questions:

Once the array is full with 10 items, how do I dynamically add more space for additional objects?  In fact, I'm thinking the array should probably have a size of 0 before the first item is added; how do I do that?

Similarly, when I delete an item (like when I delete people[1], above), how do I shrink the array down to a minimum size?  Like, how do I make the object at people[2] move to the position of people[1]?

Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

rh

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: @dandan78 Thx for the suggestion but I'm required to use a double-pointer for this exercise, not allowed to use a Vector.

Comment: @RobertHume Note that a `std::vector<double>` provides such pointer, see [`std::vector::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) nothing hinders you to use it if really needed ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thx but I'm not allowed to use the std libraries and vectors for this.

Comment: @RobertHume Poor guy! Stupid restriction! As a hint: Look up for the rule-of-(three/five/zero) to get your memory management right!

Comment: For the problem you're trying to solve, it looks like managing a linked list of `Person` instances  will serve better to solve the task.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hi again, not allowed to use linked lists either. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new array with bigger size and copy data from your current array and deallocate it.

Comment: Sorry,- even if upvoted -, that's not an appropriate answer! No way!! [flagged so]

Comment: Okay next time I use comment

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why is it not an appropriate answer?  It's actually very helpful as I had not thought of that.

Comment: @RobertHume As it stands, it's way too narrow to give answers for **all** the questions you've been going to rip up here. But OK, if you're satisfied with it ...

Comment: @RobertHume **Note:** you'll need to deallocate the previosly allocated array, to avoid memory leaks!) ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement *reallocation*.

Basically you create a second, bigger (or smaller) array, copy the existing elements there, and then discard the old array.

Do note, that you just need to copy the pointers. The objects themselves do not need to change.

Under the hood, `std::vector` does the same thing.

A common practice, when creating a bigger array, is to multiply its size by a factor somewhere between 1.5-2.

---

When removing an element, you need to shift all elements at higher indeces one element lower. Again, you just need to move the pointers, not the objects themselves.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hi again, not allowed to use linked lists. :)  Must dynamically resize the array.  I'll have to ask if this second bigger or smaller array is an appropriate solution.

Comment: While linked list have better complexity, sometimes vectors are better when you know you do only certain things and when you need random access.